# Need to correct syntax error in the Following Trigger Using phpMyAdmin to execute it

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Here is the Code i have written

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER user_address_check BEFORE INSERT ON street_master
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DECLARE @check int;
@check = STRCMP(NEW.locality_name,street_master.locality_name)
if(@check!=1)
then dbms_output.put_line('Record Already Exists');
End IF;
END;
//delimiter;
```

street_master is the table name,
locality_name is a column

The error received is:

> There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error
>   output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the
>   problem. ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 235 STR: // #1064 -
>   Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '@check; @check =
>   STRCMP(street_master.locality_name,NEW.name); if(@check!=1) ' Ã la
>   ligne 4

Comment: what do you want by trigger ? session variable do not decalare and directly assign value using  `SET`

Comment: And could you also let us know what the exact error is?

Comment: And the error is apparently of top secret classification, otherwise I cannot fathom why you are not sharing it with us.

Comment: `street_master.locality_name` what exactly do you expect its value to be in the expression? You should do a search (select) to check if the record exist or use a unique index on `locality_name`

Comment: There seems to be an error in your SQL query. The MySQL server error output below, if there is any, may also help you in diagnosing the problem.

ERROR: Unknown Punctuation String @ 235
STR: //

#1064 - Erreur de syntaxe prÃ¨s de '@check;
@check = STRCMP(street_master.locality_name,NEW.name);
if(@check!=1)
' Ã  la ligne 4

Comment: i want each row of existing locality_name column to be compared with new locality_name which i am about to insert to find possible duplicate if any

Answer (score 0):

The error you get comes from prefixing variables by @. If you use mysql compound statement syntax, then there is no need to prefix them with @, so remove it.

However, what you try to achive can be done by creating a simple unique index on `locality_name` field.

If you insist on using trigger, then the strcmp() call is incorrect, you should run a select to check if the value exists.

Comment: can you please elaborate on strcmp call ...cause i want to store the output of strcmp which to my knowledge can be 0,-1 or 1 ..so how should i do that ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is a completely different question from what you have asked. Pls post it in another question. Although, I cannot understand why you want this complicated code instead of a simple unique index.

Comment: how is it differrent..? there is a syntax error and its not only because of '@'as u mentioned earlier  ...strcmp() call is syntactically wrong .....
See I dont want to create a new entry in the db with same locality_name as the locality_name already exists in there at some unique index.....

Comment: You asked a specifiq question about a specific syntax error. My answer helped to resolve it. Now you are getting a different syntax error. Even if I helped you fix the next one, you will get a new one. The entire body of your trigger is incorrect. Plus I do not see the point of the trigger. I keep telling you that you could achive exactly the same results with a unique index. You have not provided a single reason as to why to prefer a trigger over unique index. Do you know at all what a unique index is?